# PBR textures and the Phong Shading model material parameters

Tags: opengl, graphics, textures, phong, pbr

I'm studying the Phong shading model and it looks like materials have these properties:

- Ambient, diffuse and specular coefficients (which show how they react to those properties of a light)
- Shininess of the specular component

Now, let's say I want to write a shader that doesn't have fixed values for these but takes them from PBR textures I can generate in 3D graphics software
like 3D Studio Max or Maya. Such texture sets are generally made of:

- Color/albedo/diffuse map (I guess it would replace the "diffuse" coefficient)
- Ambient occlusion (I think it would replace the "ambient" coefficient)
- Height map (no clue as to how this would be used by a shader)
- Normal map (easy one, it replaces the normal for that point)
- Metallic/specular (I think these replace the "specular" coefficient, not sure which workflow is best with the phong model)
- Roughness map (maybe it replaces the "shininess"? Not sure)

What am I not understanding correctly here? And can I do this in the first place? I read on Wikipedia that [ambient occlusion is not a local method like Phong Shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion) which probably just means the map has to be computed with some sort of global method (no issue to me as I generate it in 3D software), but it made me doubt if the Phong model is actually fit for what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: "*Now, let's say I want to write a shader that doesn't have fixed values for these but takes them from PBR textures I can generate in 3D graphics software like 3D Studio Max or Maya.*" Why are you trying to fit a square peg into a round hole? The PBR model and the Phong Shading model are both lighting models. They're mutually exclusive and not interchangeable. It's like trying to genetically engineer an apple seed to produce an orange tree; it's not going to work out very well.

Comment: PBR is not a specific model, just a way to say "hey it's based on physics", and mostly a workflow for artists meaning they have to use a certain set of textures. There are many models implementing PBR and some are based on the Phong-Blinn model. If anything, I'd like to know what should I know to adapt the Phong model to properly make use of PBR textures.

Comment: Blinn-Phong is not a physically-based lighting model. It's based on some ad-hoc assumptions that only vaguely resemble reality. If you want to use "PBR textures", then you should use a PBR-based lighting model. Phong isn't that. And attempting to shove PBR values into Phong's functions will only end in tears.

Comment: But could PBR textures applied to Phong still produce, if not "physically-based", still interesting results that "vaguely resemble reality"?

Comment: Also, could you please point me to some good resources for beginners about implementing PBR-based models?

Comment: The only part that could be reused is albedo. For the others, there is no correspondence in the Phong model. Also: Ambient Occlusion != Ambient Illumination. Normal map usually replaces the normal **in Tangent Space**. Tutorial: [See this](https://learnopengl.com/PBR/Theory)

Comment: @memememe no they can't.That's why PBR exists. Phone shading is very primitive in terms of visual effect it produces. You can't enjoy both worlds here: simplicity of phong shading code with visual fidelity of PBR. You either use this or that based on your requirements for visuals.

Comment: @BDL I see, thanks. Is there really no way to use a normal map with Phong? They seem to do it here: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Normal-Mapping

Comment: There is phong shading and the phong lighting model, which are two separate things. Phong's actual lighting model basically deals with specular reflection (it's using Lambert for the diffuse part). There is actually some PBR reformulation for the phong reflectance model in form of a properly normalized (for energy conservation) BRDF, but all of this has still nothing to do with the issue. The Phong-Based PBR model is still based on cook-torrance microfacet model and completely different from classic Phong (or Blinn-Phong) lighting.

Comment: The material textures you create in some tool are meant for a specific lighting model (used by the tool), and simply make not much sense in a different model. In the end, these are just parameters which are fed into some formula. Without knowing the formula, the parameters don't mean much by themselfs, and feeding them into some different formulas (which doesn't even have the same parameter space) isn't going to give any meaningful results.